# vertically centered Jquery slide not working in Firefox

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firefox

My JQuery UI vertical slide doesn't work in Firefox because of the `display:table-cell` used on `.label` for vertically centering the text.

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt4LK/3/)

How can I fix in Firefox yet retain the vertical centering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a div outside the label and animate the div instead:

HTML:

```
<div id="labels">
    <div>
    <p class="label" data-groupl="1">Vertically centered text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".label").parent().show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick although I'm not sure I understand exactly why.